# CollectionView without a dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, icollectionview

I need a sorting, grouping and filtering behavior of a CollectionView also with LiveShaping properties, but every .NET implementation has a Dispatcher connected to it.

Is there any implementation of the ICollectionView without a dispatcher?

Comment: What's the problem with the dispatcher? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need some lightweight object that can even be used in Console applications. To my knowledge if no System.Windows.Application has started, no Dispatcher is available.

Comment: It makes no sense to use any of the built-in implementations of the ICollectionView in a console application. I doubt it makes any sense to use the ICollectionView at all. Again: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to get the grouping, filtering and sorting capabilities of the CollectionView.

Comment: Why would you use an Collection view in a console application? You might as well group, filter and sort the source collection directly.

Comment: the source is a set of CompositeCollections where some other task/threads are changing the content. Of course I can hook into the change notifications of each CompositeCollection, but there are many different observers that need to group it into different categories. Therefore I cannot group it beforehand, but need to do it in the related subareas. Hooking into change notifications is doable, but since the collectionview already has this I see no reason to reimplement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any implementation of the ICollectionView without a dispatcher?

No, there isn't. The only class that implements this interface in the .NET Framework is the `CollectionView` class and it is a `DispatcherObject`.

So you will have to provide your own implementation or solve your issue in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> #### Remarks:
>
> The interface is implemented by the CollectionView class, which is the
>   base class for BindingListCollectionView, ListCollectionView, and
>   ItemCollection.

CollectionView derives from `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject`, so this class and all derived **will always  have** `Dispatcher` property, because `Dispatcher` property is not `virtual`, `abstract` or `override`, other way you could mark it as `sealed` and use a derived class without `Dispatcher` property.

Other remark for CollectionView:

> #### Remarks:
>
> You should not create objects of this class in your code. To create a collection view for a collection that only
>   implements IEnumerable, create a CollectionViewSource object, add your
>   collection to the Source property, and get the collection view from
>   the View property.

It is not a solution of your problem, but an answer on your question.